# Как составить регулярное выражение php?

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!
Как удалить текст между двумя слешами включая первый слеш?

/kz/blog/hello-world/
вот что должно получится /blog/hello-world/

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NtOBC1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\/?[^\/]+
```

- `^` от начала строки
- `\/?` первый слэш, если он есть
- `[^\/]+` все не слэши подряд

заменить на пустую строку

Comment: Возвращает пустую строку `preg_replace('^\/?[^\/]+', '', '/kz/blog/hello-world/');`

Comment: Спасибо!!! с `mb_ereg_replace` сработало

Comment: @ДмитрийКозлов потому что выражения заключать надо в ограничители с обоих концов, например, не просто `\d+` а `/\d+/`